# How to merge multiple block of lines into one block?

Tags: unix

I have a input file like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
13 14 15
16 17 18
...
```

I want it to be like:

```
1 2 3 7 8 9 13 14 15...
4 5 6 10 11 12 16 17 18...
```

How can do this with Unix/Linux command? Essentially, I want to combine several blocks (e.g. in the above example, every block has 2 lines) into one block.

I tried awk command. For example:

```
awk 'ORS=NR%2?FS:RS' input.txt
```

but it will merge line 1 and 2, line 3 and 4, and so on. What I want is to merge line 1 and 3..., 2 and 4...

Comment: What did you try already and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I tried awk command. 
For example: awk 'ORS=NR%2?FS:RS' input.txt, but it will merge line 1 and 2, line 3 and 4, and so on. What I want is to merge line 1 and 3..., 2 and 4...

Comment: Edit your question with this important information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using **awk**

```
$ awk -v l=2  'FNR<=l{a[FNR]=$0; next} {a[(FNR-1)%l+1]=a[(FNR-1)%l+1] FS $0} END{for(i=1; i<=l; i++) print a[i]}' file
1 2 3 7 8 9 13 14 15
4 5 6 10 11 12 16 17 18
```

You can tweak `l` to `3` or whatever as per the number of lines needed in output

```
$ awk -v l=3  'FNR<=l{a[FNR]=$0; next} {a[(FNR-1)%l+1]=a[(FNR-1)%l+1] FS $0} END{for(i=1; i<=l; i++) print a[i]}' f5
1 2 3 10 11 12
4 5 6 13 14 15
7 8 9 16 17 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Not optimal, but works :):

### Code :

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "} NR%2' file
echo
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "} NR%2==0' file
echo
```

**Or in one awk** :

```
awk '
    BEGIN{ORS=" "}
    NR%2{print; next}
    {arr[c++]=$0}
    END{print "\n"; for (a in arr) {print arr[a]}}
' file
```

### Input file :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
13 14 15
16 17 18
19 20 21
22 23 24
```

### Output :

```
1 2 3 7 8 9 13 14 15 19 20 21 
4 5 6 10 11 12 16 17 18 22 23 24
```

latest command have a leading space that I dunno how to remove without `(g|en)sub()` :)

Comment: Thanks, Gilles! That works.
In the original question, I mentioned two lines for output. This is just to make argument easier. 
If, however, I want the output to be 3 or more lines, do you have a better solution? In other words, I have this as the input:
line1
line2
line3
line4
...

and I want output to become: 
line1 line4 line7...
line2 line5 line8...
line3 line6 line9...

Comment: Added uniq awk command line. You can do math with NR (line number)